# Problem figuring out time and space complexity?

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

The question was to check whether two strings are rotation of each other or not. So, here is the function I wrote for the same:

```
 bool areRotations(string s1, string s2)
        {
            int n1 = s1.length(), n2 = s2.length();
            if (n1 != n2) return 0;
            s1 += s1;
            if (s1.find(s2) != string::npos)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
```

I just checked whether s2 is present in s1+s1, if it is there, then s1 and s2 must be rotation of each other.

**I am not able to figure out the time and space complexity of my code.** What I can understand is that it should be O(n) time complexity because first to concatenate s1 to s1, we have to create a copy of s1, and also to find s2 in s1, we have to traverse, hence making time complexity O(n).
For space also, it should be O(n), because we are making a copy of s1. **Is this correct?**

Comment: Benchmark it for various values of N, like 1, 10, 100, going up 10x each iteration. You'll very quickly find out what shape that curve takes.

Comment: This looks *O(N²)* by the way. I say that because the `find` test is potentially kind of slow, though you should run the numbers to find out for sure. Once you hit strings of length N=1e6 you'll know.

Comment: Hint: Why copy? You can always compare with a modulo on the length. *O(N)* guaranteed that way.

Comment: I think copy because, after doing s1+s1, we have to store it back to s1, since the length is doubled, we'll have to copy the whole thing to s1 (like the internal implementation of vector).

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of the way to compare with a modulo on the length, can you please explain that?

Comment: `a[i] == b[(i + n) % l]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not able to figure out the time and space complexity of my code. [...] Is this correct?

`std::string::length` runs in constant time ([since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)). The comparison and the concatenation run in linear time. But the overall algorithm could run in a non-linear time.

Indeed, the C++ standard does not actually require any specific algorithm or *guarantee a complexity* for `std::string::find`. Consequently, it is not possible to give an answers independent of the STL implementation you use.
If the implementation is naive or use a famous Boyer-Moore algorithm, the worst-case time-complexity is likely to be `O(n^2)` in your case (where `n` is the size of the input string). This could happen with inputs like `s1="aaaaaaaaaca"` and `s2="aaaaaaaaaac"`. Despite [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) provide stronger guarantees, it does not provide any search algorithm running in linear-time. To ensure a linear-time complexity, you can use the [KMP search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) (or better variants like the [2-way string-matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_string-matching_algorithm)).

Thus, with the KMP algorithm, the complexity in time and space of your solution would be `O(n)`. This is optimal as the input strings need to be read and stored somewhere (at least in your implementation).